# What is the property "Web Deploy Publish Profile" used for?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, publishing, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service

in TFS explorer, I found this property under Build Definition Editor -> Process -> Build process parameters -> 6. Publishing -- Azure Website -> Web Deploy Publish Profile:

[image]

I downloaded the publish profile, but the TFS build report the following error:

> Overall Build Process
>   Update Build Number
>   Run On Agent (reserved build agent Hosted Build Agent)
>   Create Workspace
>   Get Workspace
>   Create Label
>   Compile, Test, and Associate Changesets and Work Items
>   Compile and Test
>   Fetch Azure Web Site Publish Profile
>   Run MSBuild for Project
>   Built $/myproj/myproj/myproj.sln for default targets.
>   Built $/myproj/myproj/myproj/myproj.csproj for default targets.
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (4435): The value for PublishProfile is set to 'myproj.azurewebsites.net', expected to find the file at 'C:\a\src\myproj\myproj\myproj\Properties\PublishProfiles\myproj.azurewebsites.net' but it could not be found.
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (4449): Target ValidatePublishProfileSettings Failed
>   MSBuild Log File
>   Handle Exception
>   Create Work Item
>   Associate Changesets and Work Items
>   Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
>   **Exception Stack Trace:**
>   at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
>      at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>      at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
>   Drop Files to Drop Location
>   Work item '4: Build Failure in Build: myproj_2012-55-10_07-55.1' was opened by the build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having similar issues, there really isn't a lot of documentation on the build settings. I see from your screenshot you are using the .publishsettings file but I couldn't get this to work, instead I think you need a .pubxml file.

Try this:

- right click on the project and select publish (or publish web site)
- You will see the publish wizard, on the profile tab select import and choose your file downloaded from the azure portal.
- Close the wizard. (I published manually the first time, but I don't that is necessary). At this point visual studio should have created 3tow .pubxml files. One for webdeploy and one for ftp.
- Check this file into source control somewhere
- select the file using it's source control folder location for step 6 in the first screenshot of your question.

Hope that helps, it solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

'C:\a\src\myproj\myproj\myproj\Properties\PublishProfiles\myproj.azurewebsites.net' but it could not be found.

Do you have a profile located in that directory? That probably is the issue..it needs to be in that directory.

Comment: First of all it's a target in the azure server, two, why is it looking for that stupid filename?

Comment: Good point that it is not on the client.  Is the publish file checked in and part of the build process?

Comment: Yes at the path I specified.

Comment: c:\a\src' what is it with this path - it keeps looking in that path on my visual studio - and says it can't find the files when it builds.